# Cassandra repair - lots of streaming in case of incremental repair with Leveled Compaction enabled

Tags: cassandra

I use Cassandra for gathering time series measurements. To enable nice partitioning, beside *device-id* I added *day-from-UTC-beginning* and a *bucket* created on the basis of a written measurement. The time is added as a clustering key. The final key can be written as

> ((device-id, day-from-UTC-beginning, bucket), measurement-uuid)

Queries against this schema in majority of cases take whole rows with the given *device-id* and *day-from-UTC-beginning* using *IN* for buckets. Because of this query schema [Leveled Compaction](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/leveled-compaction-in-apache-cassandra) looked like a perfect match, as it ensures with great probability that a row is held by one SSTable.
Running incremental repair was fine, when appending to the table was disabled. Once, the repair was run under the write pressure, lots of streaming was involved. It looked like more data was streamed than was appended after the last repair.

I've tried using multiple tables, one for each day. When a day ended and no further writes were made to a given table, repair was running smoothly. I'm aware of [thousands of tables overhead](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12329/what-are-the-penalties-of-using-many-thousands-of-column-families-or-keyspaces) though it looks like it's only one feasible solution.

What's the correct way of combining Leveled Compaction with incremental repairs under heavy write scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Leveled Compaction is not a good idea when you have a write heavy workload. It is better for a read/write mixed workload when read latency matters. Also if your cluster is already pressed for I/O, switching to leveled compaction will almost certainly only worsen the problem. So ensure you have SSDs.
At this time size tiered is the better choice for a write heavy workload. There are some improvements in 2.1 for this though.

Comment: As I mentioned, the heavy read access pattern is to scan through whole row. I tested the size tiered compaction and it brought a lot of overhead. Moving to Leveled made the read latency to the minimum which is required for my scenario. As far as I can notice, discs IO are not the problem, I've got JBOD on board and it handles pressure well.
The question is, why so much streaming occurs during repair, when the keyspace is under write pressure? Is it the compaction related thing?